# Llenar un DropDownList a medida que se vaya escribiendo asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlist

necesito llenar un DropDownList a medida que el usuario vaya escribiendo en el mismo DropDownList. Cabe destacar que soy nuevo en esto. mediante una consulta de SQL, mil gracias a todos.

```
<div class="form-group row"> 
   <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Capacidad</label> 
   <div class="col-sm-9"> 
      <asp:DropDownList ID="Capacidad" class="form-control" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"> 
         <asp:ListItem Value="0">Seleccione...</asp:ListItem> 
      </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
</div
```

Comment: ¿Que intentaste e investigaste? ¿Es una pregunta de C#, SQL o ambas?

Comment: <div class="form-group row">
 <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Capacidad</label>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="Capacidad" class="form-control" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Seleccione...</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Me parece que lo que tú quieres es un `autocomplete`, no puedes hacerlo con un dropdowlist.  tienes que hacerlo con un Textbox (input text)

Comment: @Yussef ahora que lo mencionas, creo que hay un control que integra sugerencias a partir de una lista o un arreglo.

Comment: @Mateo Nativo en HTML está la propiedad `list` de un input que asemeja el autocompletar solo que no es vinculante, es decir de todas formas puedes escribir en un valor que no pertenece a lista (a menos que hagas un js que valide). Y en ASPX creo que había uno que se llamaba AutoCompleteExtender